# Toggle Show/Hide Div Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, navigation

I have a problem with my positioning on a mobile navigation element layout of my design.

Because I have used various Z-index’s and positioning’s when you click on the Nav button to displays mobile navigational links, part of my design is still visible and it obscures the 'return back to normal' nav button.

What I would like to do is add some more JavaScript to the code that it will remove/hide the part of my normal design that is obscuring the Nav button when clicked and then toggle back to display normally when it’s clicked again.

Here is the JS I am using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //move nav element position according to window width
    moveNavigation();
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ? setTimeout(moveNavigation, 300) : window.requestAnimationFrame(moveNavigation);
    });

    //mobile version - open/close navigation
    $('.cd-nav-trigger').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('header').hasClass('nav-is-visible')) $('.moves-out').removeClass('moves-out');

        $('header').toggleClass('nav-is-visible');
        $('.cd-main-nav').toggleClass('nav-is-visible');
        $('.cd-main-content').toggleClass('nav-is-visible');
    });

    //mobile version - go back to main navigation
    $('.go-back').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-main-nav').removeClass('moves-out');
    });

    //open sub-navigation
    $('.cd-subnav-trigger').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-main-nav').toggleClass('moves-out');
    });

    function moveNavigation(){
        var navigation = $('.cd-main-nav-wrapper');
        var screenSize = checkWindowWidth();
        if ( screenSize ) {
            //desktop screen - insert navigation inside header element
            navigation.detach();
            navigation.insertBefore('.cd-nav-trigger');
        } else {
            //mobile screen - insert navigation after .cd-main-content element
            navigation.detach();
            navigation.insertAfter('.cd-main-content');
        }
    }

    function checkWindowWidth() {
        var mq = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('header'), '::before').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/"/g, '').replace(/'/g, "");
        return ( mq == 'mobile' ) ? false : true;
    }
});
```

So what I would like to do is add to this a function the removes the div: “#bar_bg_default” onclick and then displays it again when its clicked again.

Something like this would work, but how would I fit it into my Nav JS code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('bar_bg_default');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #bar_bg_default</a>
<div id="bar_bg_default">This is foo</div>
```

Comment: Jsfiddle would be extremly helpful.